# Auto-scaling t3 instances by cpu utilization?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

`t3` instances are [burstable above baseline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html#burstable-performance-instances-credit-table), so how does this have to be considered for auto-scaling by `CPUUtilization`?

Let's say we use `t3.small` [instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/burstable-credits-baseline-concepts.html) with:

- 24 CPU credits earned per hour
- 2 vCPUs
- 20% Baseline performance per vCPU

I would set this scaling trigger for `CPUUtilization`:

- Statistic: Average
- Unit: Percent
- Period: 5min
- Breach duration: 5min
- Upper threshold: 15%
- Lower threshold: 5%

So the upper threshold is set just below the baseline to avoid the additional cost when staying above the baseline for too long (and using up CPU credits).

In addition I set a CloudWatch alert when `CPUUtilization` of any instance stays above 20% for too long. This would at least get triggered when auto scaling has reached the max. number of allowed instances.

Does this all make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It is not advisable to use CPU Utilization as a metric for Auto Scaling when using T1/2/3 burstable instance types.

The reason is that the CPU on these instances can be artificially limited, thereby giving a false impression of how busy they are.

If you activate the "Unlimited" option, then this is okay because instance can burst as required without limit. Do not be afraid of the extra charge since it only costs extra if it exceeds a monthly average and you'll only be paying for CPU that was actually "used" when they were busy.

Alternatively, choose a different (non-burstable) instance type.

Comment: t3 seems to be the best fit, but the possible artificial limitation is an interesting aspect. What are your thoughts on switching to latency instead?

Comment: You'll need to measure the latency to determine whether it is a reliable factor. Or, generate a custom metric that reflects what the application is doing. It all depends what the application does when things get busy -- it could be RAM that gets tight, or disk access, or a database, or... something else!

Comment: Practically speaking, using this metric for 2 days now, it seems to work fine. Is the artificial limit a theoretical or practical one?

Comment: @Manuel Hoping to followup with you on this as I face similar dilemmas now.  Did the original plan in your question end up working out for you?  If not what did you find works best?

Comment: It worked for some time with scale-up threshold at >18%, scale-down threshold at <14% with unlimited option on. Turned out that this is not efficient, as more instances than needed were active; the problem especially showed when scaling to >30 instances. I think it depends on your use case, but once you scale, these small inefficiencies add up to a point where they have to be addressed due to costs.